# How to batch translate a group of words?

Tags: linguistics

I want to translate a group of words into simplified Chinese more quickly:

```
    wordlist1 = 
      ToString /@ {abate, aberrant, abound, abrogate, abstain, abstruse, 
        accede, accessory, accommodate, accredit, acquaint, acquisitive, 
        adduce, adept, admonish, adore, adorn, affiliate, affluent, 
        agitate, agony, agreeable, album, allegiance, allegorical};
    WordTranslation[#, "Chinese"] & /@ wordlist1
```

But the result of the above code is traditional Chinese. If I specify "SimplifiedChinese" as the parameter, I still can't get the desired result. How can I get the result of simplified Chinese?

```
    {\[LongDash],\[LongDash],\[LongDash],\[LongDash],{戒},\[LongDash],\[LongDash],{附件},{提供住宿},\[LongDash],{使認識},\[LongDash],\[LongDash],\[LongDash],\[LongDash],{崇拜},{裝飾},\[LongDash],{豐富的},{煽動},{極度痛苦},{同意的},{簿},{忠誠},\[LongDash]}
```

---

```
BaiduTranslate[str_, from_ : "en", to_ : "zh"] := 
 Block[{q, appid, key, salt, sign, data},
    q = str;
  
  appid = "20190314000277077";(*你的appid，如何申请请自行百度*)
  key = "sjRd6QGeuLAR1jTr0d3G";
  
    salt = ToString@RandomInteger[2^32];
    sign = Hash[StringJoin[appid, q, salt, key], "MD5", "HexString"];
  data = Import[
    StringJoin[
     "http://api.fanyi.baidu.com/api/trans/vip/translate?q=", 
     URLEncode@q, "&from=", from, "&to=", to, "&appid=", appid, 
     "&salt=", salt, "&sign=", sign], "RawJSON"];
    data["trans_result"][[1]]["dst"]]
BaiduTranslate /@ wordlist1
```

If I use the above code, I will get a lot of word results as `"KeyAbsent"("dst")`, how can I modify it to better translate this group of words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematica and the Wolfram Language have [built-in multilingual dictionaries](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/LinguisticData.html) to translate between languages, with functions including [`WordTranslation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WordTranslation.html) and [`TextTranslation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextTranslation.html).

`WordTranslation` and `TextTranslation` both accept a list of words for translation. Using lists works more quickly than translating one word at a time with `WordTranslation[#, "Chinese"] & /@ wordlist1`.

`WordTranslation` understands a set of standard names of languages or their Wolfram Language entities. It does not support simplified Chinese.

`TextTranslation` requires internet connectivity and uses external services. It accepts "ChineseSimplified" and "ChineseTraditional" variations for translating to Chinese.

Here are examples of translating a list of English words to Chinese. The examples use `TextTranslation` for simplified and traditional Chinese, and `WordTranslation` for comparison.

```
wordlist = {"abate", "aberrant", "abound", "abrogate", "abstain", "abstruse", "accede",
  "accessory", "accommodate", "accredit", "acquaint", "acquisitive", "adduce", "adept",
  "admonish", "adore", "adorn", "affiliate", "affluent", "agitate", "agony", "agreeable", 
  "album", "allegiance", "allegorical"};

TableForm[Transpose[{wordlist,
  TextTranslation[wordlist, "ChineseSimplified"],
  TextTranslation[wordlist, "ChineseTraditional"],
  WordTranslation[wordlist, "Chinese"]}],
TableHeadings -> {None,
  {"English", "Chinese simplified", "Chinese traditional", "WordTranslation"}}]
```

| English | Chinese simplified | Chinese traditional | WordTranslation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abate | 方丈 | 方丈 | Missing[NotAvailable] |
| aberrant | 异常 | 異常 | Missing[NotAvailable] |
| abound | 比比皆是 | 比比皆是 | Missing[NotAvailable] |
| abrogate | 废除 | 廢除 | Missing[NotAvailable] |
| abstain | 投弃权票 | 投棄權票 | 戒 |
| abstruse | 深奥 | 深奧 | Missing[NotAvailable] |
| accede | 访问 | 訪問 | Missing[NotAvailable] |
| accessory | 配件 | 配件 | 附件 |
| accommodate | 容纳 | 容納 | 提供住宿 |
| accredit | 授权 | 授權 | Missing[NotAvailable] |
| [...] | [...] | [...] | [...] |
| allegorical | 寓言 | 寓言 | Missing[NotAvailable] |

Comment: The function `TextTranslation` call Google translation, which requires payment, I would like to know whether Baidu translation or other ways can replace the default Google translation options.

Comment: @Alittlemouseonthepampas – I don't know enough Chinese to check Baidu's policy or documentation for the API you're using, so I can't help with your `BaiduTranslate` function (I used a bunch of my Wolfram service credits while testing my answer). Are the `KeyAbsent` results caused by words that Baidu can't translate? [Google translate](https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing) includes a free $10 usage credit per month. Does Baidu have a similar policy or usage limits? I've asked about Wolfram's service credit policy; free service credits were included with my license.

Comment: Youdao translation provides some free Chinese-English API translation services:`YoudaoTranslate[str_, from_ : "en", to_ : "zh"] := 
 Block[{q, appid, key, salt, sign, data},
   q = str;
   appid = "neverland";(*你的appid，如何申请请自行百度*)
   key = "969918857";(*你的key*)
  data = Import[
    StringJoin["http://fanyi.youdao.com/openapi.do?keyfrom=", appid, 
     "&key=", key, "&type=data&doctype=json&version=1.1&q=", 
     URLEncode@q], "RawJSON"];
   data["translation"][[1]]];
YoudaoTranslate["an apple a day"]`